# How to test PhoneGap app in Sony Ericsson x8?

Tags: android

Hi how can I test a PhoneGap app in Sony Ericsson x8 which has Android 2.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it output a .apk file for you? Or does this IDE create web apps only? If it will give you an apk file you just need to paste it to your SD card and find it with a file browser app (OI File Manager is one of many free ones) then click on it, it should prompt you to install. You must also go to Settings->Applications and ensure that 'Unkown Sources' is turned on before you do this. If it is outputing a web app then Id imagine you'll need to host it online somewhere and navigate to it with the devices browser.